# Spark SQL "select column AS ..." not finding column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run an 'SQL' query on a Spark DataFrame. I have registered the name of the df as table and now I am trying to run a select on a column where I apply a udf and then pickup the rows that pass a certain condition.

The problem is that on my `WHERE` clause is referencing the modified column but it is not able to see the names declared with `AS`.

```
    DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("delimiter", delimiter)
            .load(path);
    df.registerTempTable("df");

    String sqlDfQuery = "SELECT parseDateTime(start) as start1 FROM df WHERE start1 > 1";
    if (sqlContext.sql(sqlDfQuery).take(1) != null) return true;
```

when I am running that I am getting back

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'start1' given input columns: [scores, start, ...

`parseDateTime` is a UDF defined like that

```
    sqlContext.udf().register("parseDateTime", (String dt) -> new DateTime(dt).getMillis(), DataTypes.LongType);
```

Should I not be trying to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because it applies the filters before aliases.

You could do a nested select statement to solve this issue.
Something like the following:

```
String sqlDfQuery = "SELECT start1 FROM (
                              SELECT parseDateTime(start) AS start1 FROM df) TMP
                     WHERE start1 > 1 ";
```